# How to redirect only part of output produced by a commmand?

Tags: command-line, bash, python, io

Let's suppose I run a python program named `test.py` and want to save all it's output in a file.
We can easily do that via `python3 test.py > output.txt`

However, If the program produces a **lot** of lines, what is the most efficient way in bash to reduce the amount of data written to a file?

> Example: Save every second line of the program's output, or perhaps every `x` lines.

So how can I do it using bash only, preferably something that updates the file in real-time?

**Edit:-** SteelDriver's answer seems to be working. However, Can someone also tell me a command that prints the first `x` lines as it is, but after `x` lines, outputs every `y` lines and stores them in the file?

Comment: Ubuntu comes with a rich feature set of shell-based text processing tools: Awk, sed, cat, cut, grep, tail, head, etc. There are many online orientations to these tools just a Search Engine away; try them. "Efficient" depends upon what you want to accomplish and how you want to measure it.

Comment: @user535733 Efficient would be simply the fastest method with the least resource overhead

Comment: You need to specify *in your question*, not in comments. Which resource? Time? Something else? RAM? CPU? Energy? Some combination? Your question should also detail what you have already tried and how you measured it. In other words, you question seems too broad to me. We're not going to duplicate all those online guides for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe the program's standard output through another program as a filter - for example to write every 10th line starting with the first

```
python3 test.py | sed -n '1~10p' > output.txt
```

or

```
python3 test.py | awk '!((NR-1)%10)' > output.txt
```

If you really need to use bash only, then you could replace sed/awk by a shell loop using a counter and a conditional arithmetic expression to select the desired lines - but I would not recommend it. See for example [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) .

Comment: +1 Sorry for the misunderstanding, I mean that the solution should not use any python or require modifications to the program, but your solution seems the most appropriate. Also, is there a way to skip the first few lines or something like that?

Comment: Look at `man head` and `man tail` and so many more bash tools to process text output.

Comment: @vanadium I am aware of those commands, but I think they are used as `head -5 output.txt` to print out the first 5 lines, which does not serve my purpose - I want the same to be done in real time. + I don't know the length of the file formed